# How to upload mobile contacts to firebase storage using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to create an app in flutter in which I want to save or upload all mobile phone contacts to firebase storage when permission is granted do all this programatically. I'm using `permission_handler` for permissions and want to use `contact_services` plugin for contacts. PLease give me code for this I have tried many times but failed.

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'calendar.dart';
import 'info.dart';


void main() => runApp(const PageScaffoldApp());

class PageScaffoldApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageScaffoldApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      home: HomeScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Widget> data = [CalendarScreen(), const InfoScreen()];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _askPermissions();
  }

  Future<void> _askPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getContactPermission();
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getContactPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
      return permissionStatus;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(

      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(

        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar_circle),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar_circle_fill),
            label: 'Calendar',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.info_circle),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.info_circle_fill),
            label: 'Info',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return data[index];

          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [flutter contact package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts) for fetch all mobile contact.

Example :

```
    late List<Contact> contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.getDataList();
    _getContactPermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getContactPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.contact.request();
    if (status.isGranted) {
      contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(
          withProperties: true, withPhoto: true);
      for (var userContact in contacts) {
        await fireStore.collection('userContact').add({
          'fname': userContact.name.first,
          'lname': userContact.name.last,
          'contact': contact.phones.isNotEmpty
              ? contact.phones.first.number
              : 'Not available'
        });
      }
    } else {
      // handle error
    }
  }
```

i hope it will work for you.

Comment: `controller.getDataList();`  undefined name controller

and I have replaced this `await fireStore.collection('userContact').add` to this `await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userContact').add` otherwise it show undefined name firestore.

Bro I'm new in flutter pls help

Comment: Sorry for one mistake just remove controller.getDataList(): and second thing you did right FirebaseFirestore instance now you can add contacts to collection